# Who came up with the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\left[a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history

Though we can prove this it is not something that comes up intutively.

Our ancestors must have been interested in factorising $a^3+b^3+c^3$ but why find it for $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ ?

Comment: Might be more suitable for [History of Science and Mathematics.SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I prefer the pure symmetric polynomial formula: $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)\left[(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\right]$$ More generally, we get $$a^n+b^n+c^n=\sum_{i+2j+3k=n} (-1)^j \frac{n}{i+j+k}\binom{i+j+k}{i,j,k}(a+b+c)^i(ab+ac+bc)^j(abc)^k$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Shouldn't the second formula have some coefficients in it beyond $(-1)^j$, to produce the $3$'s in the expression for $a^3+b^3+c^3$?

Comment: Yep, forgot the coefficient. Edited.

Comment: May be this factorisation came up on trying to prove the A.G.M. inequality for $3$ numbers, as it can be proved this expression is positive, for all $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: This is equivalent to [Newton's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) $p_3=e_1p_2-e_2p_1+3e_3\,$, which dates it back to the XVII century.

Comment: thank you all of you for your comments and answers.I am just in high school so your answers are a little tough to comprehend. But still I got the basic idea.

Comment: On the wiki page (in french sorry) it says that it's the Gauss identity .https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identit%C3%A9_remarquable#Identit%C3%A9_de_Gauss .But be careful with this information .

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is
$$ \det( aI + b W + c W^2 ) $$
where
$$
W =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b & c & a
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Right. It follows that the polynomial is multiplicative: as $W^3 = I$ and $W^4 = W,$ we get
$$ (aI + b W + c W^2)(pI + q W + r W^2) = xI + y W + z W^2,    $$
where
$$ x = ap + br + cq, $$
$$ y = aq + bp + cr, $$
$$ z = ar + bq + cp.  $$
Then, by multiplication of determinants,
$$ (a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc)(p^3 + q^3 + r^3 - 3pqr) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz $$

Comment: And, of course, modulo $a+b+c$, the determinant is $0$ since the rows/columns add up to $0$ modulo $a+b+c$.

Answer (score 5):

People were interested already a long time ago in the Diophantine equation, 
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3-nabc=0,
$$
for $n\ge 1$. For a modern treatment see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa73/aa7331.pdf).
The case $n=3$ inspired - perhaps- to look out for factorisations.

Answer (score 3):

This might better be a comment, but I'm posting it as an answer.

Let $S_n=a^n+b^n+c^n$.

More generally, we have ($n\ge 3$ is an integer, $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$) $$\begin{align}S_n=&S_{n-1}(a+b+c)\\&-S_{n-2}(ab+bc+ca)\\&+S_{n-3}(abc)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the history of this identity, but here is a derivation based on the properties of determinants.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a &c &b\\
b &a &c\\
c &b &a
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
a+b+c &a+b+c &a+b+c\\
b &a &c\\
c &b &a
\end{vmatrix} = (a+b+c) \begin{vmatrix}
1 &1 & 1\\
b &a &c\\
c &b &a
\end{vmatrix} $$

Expanding the determinant on the left, we have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$$
and expanding the determinant on the right we have
$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$
so these two expressions are equal.