# The equation $a^3+b^3+c^3=kabc$

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in the equation $a^3+b^3+c^3=kabc$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$. We have by AM-GM:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 \geqslant 3abc \implies k \geqslant 3$$
Since $k=3$ is the equality case, the solutions for $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$ is $(a,b,c)=(x,x,x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$. However, it is not clear whether it is possible to solve any case $k>3$, atleast in an elementary fashion.

For which values of $k$ has this equation been solved? Are there any results for any $k>3$ where $k \in \mathbb{Q}$ (or specifically in $k \in \mathbb{N}$)?

EDIT : I must specify that as the equation is homogeneous, it is obvious that you can generate a family of solutions from a primitive solution by scaling. Thus, I consider only the cases where $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. It can easily be seen that this also means they are pairwise relatively prime.

I am aware that there are 'some' solutions for specific $k$. This doesn't answer my question. I am looking for characterization of all primitive solutions, generating infinitely many primitive solutions, proving infinitude of primitive solutions, non-existence of solutions etc. for specific $k$.

Comment: I don't know for which $k$ there is a solution, but for any $a,b,c$ you get some rational $k=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$.

Comment: Google ["ternary cubic" + Diophantine](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ternary+cubic%22+Diophantine). The top hit for me is [*On some classes of homogeneous ternary cubic diophantine equations*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afm/1485896418) by Erik Dofs (1975), which seems very relevant and has several references that are probably worth pursuing. Also relevant is the google search ["cubic" + Pell's + equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cubic%22+Pell%27s+equation).

Comment: You can see lots of $k\in\Bbb N$ solutions [here](https://repl.it/repls/MeanIllegalPlot). They don't suggest a hypothesis to try to prove, so I suspect this problem won't be solved in general. However, special choices of $k$ may be more feasible.

Comment: See also pp. 588-595 (and maybe also elsewhere) in [**History of the Theory of Numbers**, Volume II. Diophantine Analysis](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo02dickuoft/page/588/mode/2up) by Leonard Eugene Dickson (1920).

Comment: Further links can be found at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209178/who-came-up-with-the-identity-a3b3c3-3abc-abc-lefta2b2c2-ab-bc-c), also with the top hit Erik Dofs.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is it possible to generate more primitive solutions from one primitive solution? The Erik Dofs paper specifies something about a chord and tangent process concerning elliptic curves.

Answer (score 1):

We can get solutions one by one through seeking rational roots of a cubic equation.

Assume wlog $a\le b\le c$.  Pick values of $a$ and $b$ that meet the above ordering requirement.  Then render a cubic equation for $c$:

$c^3-(kab)+(a^3+b^3)=0$

And solve the original equation for $k$:

$k=(a^3+b^3+c^3)/(abc)$

We then have a solution if $c$ divides $a^3+b^3$ and $abc$ divides $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Suppose, for instance, $a=b=1$.  Then $c|2$ by the first criterion.  We find that the second criterion also holds for each candidate $c=1$ and $c=2$ giving two solutions $(a,b,c,k)=(1,1,1,3)$ and $(a,b,c,k)=(1,1,2,5)$.

Now try $a=1, b=2$. Here $c\in\{1,3,9\}$ by the first criterion, but we cover $c=1<b$ with a smaller ordered pair for $(a,b)$.  For $c=3$ we infer $(a,b,c,k)=(1,2,3,6)$ and for $c=9$ we succeed with $(a,b,c,k)=(1,2,9,41)$.

Answer (score 0):

Equation, $a^3+b^3+c^3=k(abc)$

Has parametric solution:

$k=(m^2+8)$

$a=m(m^2+3)$

$b=(m^2+4m+7)$

$c=(4m-m^2-7)$

For, $m=2$,we get,$(a,b,c,k)=[(14),(19),(-3),(12)]$

For, $m=3$,we get,$(a,b,c,k)=[(9),(7)(-1),(17)]$

Comment: I did not down-vote, but the solution fails because the parameters are supposed to be natural numbers.