# Algebraic equation $a^3 + b^3 + 1 = 3ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The real numbers $a$ and $b$ are in are related by relationship: $a^3 + b^3 + 1 = 3ab$. Determine the value of $a+b$.

At first, I tried to use cubic equation but it was pointless.
Then I tried to rearrange this equation.

$$a^3 + b^3 + 1 - 3ab =0$$

$$a + a^2 - 2ab - ab + b + b^2 + 1 =0$$

$$(a + b)^2 + a - ab + b = -1$$
Here is where I got stuck.

Later I tried to figure out what the value of $a + b$ has to be to satisfy the equation.
I think that a + b has to be equal to $-1$.

I would like to know if it is correct and how to get to the solution by rearranging the equation.

Comment: What happens when $a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc = 0$?

Comment: Also, how is $a^3 = a+a^2$?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209178/who-came-up-with-the-identity-a3b3c3-3abc-abc-lefta2b2c2-ab-bc-c?noredirect=1) and others for a solution, with the first comment by D S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you may have a good idea how to factorise $a^3+b^3+1-3ab$, but even if you don't, here is a little bit more pedestrian way that leads to the same outcome.

First, introduce the substitution $z=a+b$ i.e. $b=z-a$. The question turns into "for which value of $z$ does the equation $a^3+(z-a)^3+1=3a(z-a)$ have solutions in $a$?"

Simplifying, the equation turns into:

$$z^3-3z^2a+3za^2+1=3az-3a^2$$

i.e.

$$(3z+3)a^2+(-3z^2-3z)a+(z^3+1)=0$$

which is:

$$(z+1)(3a^2-3za+z^2-z+1)=0$$

So, if $z=-1$, this equation is satisfied for every $a$. If $z\ne -1$, then we can cancel the factor $z+1$, and the discriminant of the remaining quadratic equation $3a^2-3za+z^2-z+1=0$ (where $a$ is unknown) must be non-negative:

$$(-3z)^2-12(z^2-z+1)\ge 0$$

i.e.

$$-3(z-2)^2\ge 0$$

which is true if and only if $z=2$, and now we can solve the above quadratic equation for $a$:

$$3a^2-3za+z^2-z+1=0$$
$$3a^2-6a+3=0$$
$$3(a-1)^2=0$$

which gives $a=1$ and $b=z-a=1$.

Thus, the entire set of solutions is:

- $a$: arbitrary, $b=-1-a$, which gives $a+b=-1$
- A single additional solution $a=b=1$, which gives $a+b=2$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Your working is incorrect as pointed out by @DS.

Your observation regarding $a+b+1$ possibly being zero is however an important one.

$$a^3+b^3+1-3ab=(a+b+1)(a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b).$$
Therefore one solution is given by $a+b=-1$.

For $a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b$ to be zero, $a$ and $b$ must clearly be positive. W.l.g. suppose $b\ge a$, then
$$a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b=(a-1)^2+(b-1)(b-a)$$
Therefore the only other solution is given by $a=b=1$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$a^3 + b^3 + 1 - 3ab =0 \implies a^3 + b^3 =3ab- 1$$

then

$$(a+b)^3 = 3ab(a+b+1)-1 \iff (a+b)^3+1 = 3ab(a+b+1) $$

$$\color{red}{(a+b+1)}\color{blue}{((a+b)^2-(a+b)+1)=3ab}\color{red}{(a+b+1)}$$

that is $\color{red}{a+b+1=0} \iff \boxed{a+b=-1}$ or

$$\color{blue}{(a+b)^2-(a+b)+1-3ab=0}$$

which, since $(a+b)^2-(a+b)+1>0$ has solution only for $a,b >0$ then consider $2$ cases

1. $a\neq b$ by AM-GM $\implies 3ab< \frac 3 4(a+b)^2$

$$(a+b)^2-(a+b)+1-\frac3 4(a+b)^2<0 \iff \frac14(a+b)^2-(a+b)+1<0$$

which is impossible.

2. $a=b$

$$(a+b)^2-(a+b)+1-3ab=0\iff a^2-2a+1=0$$

which leads to $a=b=1 \implies \boxed{a+b=2}$.